# ExternalQuestion worker limitation

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

I have two different use cases on Mechanical Turk. The first one is where there is one 'task' and I need ten unique workers to complete it. So, 10 HITs and only one worker can do one HIT. An example of this might be a survey in which I want ten people to fill it out:

```
q = ExternalQuestion(external_url="http://example.com/mturk", frame_height=800)
conn.create_hit(question=q, reward = 0.05, max_assignments=10, title='My Survey')
```

This produces the required result, as it only shows one available HIT to a worker

[image]

How would I then produce a 'task' where it has 10 HITs but one person (or ten) can do them all? An example of this might be someone entering in whether a picture is a boy or a girl. And they should be able to skip one to go on to the next:

[image]

[image]

How would I do this second use case with `create_hit` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do 10 separate `create_hit` operations, each with a different question value. Essentially, HITs that have the same HITType (i.e., display properties like title, reward, etc.) are grouped visually in the worker interface, so the difference between your two use cases is that the first involves only one HIT (with multiple assignments, each available to different workers) whereas the second involves multiple HITs that share a HITType (with one assignment per HIT, all of which are available to any worker).

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you very much for your help here. It makes me wonder why the Mechanical Turk documentation isn't more descriptive here.